# Approximating $e^{\frac 1 {10}}$ with Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Approximate $e^{\frac 1 {10}}$ such that the error won't be larger than $10^{-3}$.

I tried to use the expansion for $e^x$ but the error is too large even beyond order 4.

So I think the only other option is the expansion of $e^{1/x}$ around $x=0$, but from deriving that function it's easy to see that we can't place $x=0$ because of division by $0$... Is there a way to expand that function around $x=0$?

Interestingly enough, WA gives me four different series for this function which out of them only the following give a good approximation when placing $x=10$:

[image]

But I can't reach to this polynomial on my own because of division by $0$.

I used this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f9476968629e1163bd4a3ba839d60925

**Notes:** no integrals, also, I'm pretty sure this should be solved only with rational expressions, so having $e$ in the calculation is probably wrong.

We use the following formula to find the error:

[image]

Comment: Please show us more of your work when you tried using the expansion for $e^x$.  The error there really shouldn't be "too large even beyond order $4$."

Comment: Just use a couple more terms in the power series for $e^x$. Of course there's no such thing as a fastest converging series, but the series for $e^x$ is one of the fastest converging *useful* series there is.

Comment: What do you mean by "the error is too large even beyond order 4"? With $4$ terms of the series I get $e^{1/10}\approx 6631/6000 \approx 1.105167$, which is pretty close to the actual value $\approx 1.105171$

Comment: I think I had a calculation error... thanks guys. Well there's still the mystery of  the expansion of $e^{1/x}$ around $x=0$. Is there a way to do it and reach the expression in my question?

Comment: What formulas do you know for the estimation of the error?

Comment: @GitGud this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/1/1/3/1135b7cc9a5a89e532b48c7a4eeaf0d0.png

Comment: @kuhaku Add that information to the question, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|e^x-\sum_{i\le  k} {x^i \over i!} | = | \sum_{i > k} {x^i \over i!} | \le
{1 \over (k+1)! } \sum_{i > k} {|x|^i} = {1 \over (k+1)! }|x|^{k+1} {1 \over 1-|x|}$.

With $x={1\over 10}$, a few computations shows that $k=2$ satisfies 
${1 \over (k+1)! }|x|^{k+1} {1 \over 1-|x|} < {1 \over 10^3}$.

Comment: @kuhaku If you really must use [Lagrange's Remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder), the idea is similar to the one used here.

Comment: @GitGud I can just expand a polynomial to the third order and then approximate the error separately using Lagrange's remainder no?

Comment: @kuhaku Second order is enough.

Comment: What happened to the $e^c$ in the remainder?

Comment: What remainder are you referring to?

Comment: Lagrange's/Cauchy's remainder for estimating the error.

Comment: Well, it depends in what you want to do, the Taylor remainder involves using $e$, which seems to be circular. The above estimate avoids this.